# Microsoft Graph API - How to retrieve deleted outlook event details by event id

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-calendar

We are subscribing(using Graph API Webhooks) to calendar events that are deleted by the user. When the listener receive notification payload, it will have event id and we would like to get more details about the event to take further action.

when queried by deleted event id, Graph API doesn’t return event details.

I can retrieve deleted messages from deleted messages folder but NOT deleted events.

do we have a way to retrieve deleted events using Graph API or should we depend on EWS?

Comment: is there any solution for this ? . i am getting `ErrorItemNotFound` when retire the event details by event id

Answer (score 1):

I believe currently Graph API doesn't support retrieving deleted events from delted messages folder.